# Can I use Swiper library in React native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, swiper.js

I am attempting to use this Swiper (https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper) in my react native mobile app follow this instruction for React Component: https://swiperjs.com/react

So far it's still not working, some errors I saw were:

- invariant violation view config getter callback for component 'div' must be a function (received undefined). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
- Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

Just wondering does this library support React Native?

Answer (score 1):

React native doesn't use `div` so from your error message, likely it is meant for ReactJS web.

Try

https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper